# Can't download a file on a different device, using apache2 http server and ubuntu 12.10

Tags: http, ubuntu, apache2

I want to be able to download a file from my apache2 server, on another device, (my router). Currently, I'm able to download the file from a browser on my computer (locally), but I am unable to get it from my router.

My eth0 is 192.168.0.5

My router is 192.168.0.72

My apache2 server address is 192.168.0.5

Does anybody know what I should do? I am kind of stumped! I want to download a file from apac.he2.server.add/file on my router.

Comment: What utility are you using to complete the transfer? And are these protocol ports open?

Comment: I'm not sure if the ports are forwarded. I can ping the pc from the router. I plan on using a python script to fire commands at the router and stimulate downloads etc.

Comment: Okay, but how specifically are you going to download? Are you using ftp, or sftp, or tftp or raw binary transfer, or what? :)

Comment: oh right! i hadn't actually thought about this. i think i will use raw binary transfer.

Comment: Well, let me get this straight: Are you going to try and use a python utility on your router to download a file with raw binary transfer to your router? Can I ask you what you're trying to accomplish, as there might be an easier solution?

Comment: Meaning: Rare indeed is the need to download files *to* a router.

Comment: Yes, I know! I am simulating a server which updates the config automatically. I have a capture of how the router communicates with the server, and will be scripting the automation that runs between the two. It is for testing, so unfortunately it has to be done this way! I am not entirely sure how the downloads run, there is a series of commands which set the download up.

Comment: Updates the config to what? You really should avoid using your router as a stand-in for a remote server, because it's only really good at being a router. Unless you are talking about router config? Or what exactly?

Comment: I'm talking about the router config.

Comment: Are you trying to inject your own router configuration? You should also google for your specific brand of router and find out what utility (almost ubiquitously tftp -- trivial ftp) your router uses to do the actual file transfers.

Comment: what happens is the router calls the server and looks for its config/image/whatever, and then the download starts. there is a httpclient setting on the router, which will be used to download the files i think?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. But can I ask what you're trying to do by replicating this process?

Comment: Ah, it downloads the file over TFTP!

Comment: Thought so. Almost all "normal" routers use tftp and run a form of busybox (which is like a kind of stripped-down linux sort of).